# How can I make Windows10 not connect automatically to every open hotspot it can see?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

I switched my Windows 10 laptop on before switching on my ISP router. I hoped that as soon as the router switches on, my laptop will connect to it through Wi-Fi.

But instead I was surprised to see my laptop automatically connecting to an open hotspot it had in range. As soon as I manually disconnected it from this open hotspot it connected to my router.

I'd like to make my Windows10 laptop only automatically connect to these WiFi networks I mark for autoconnecting, and ignore any other networks until I tel it to connect to one.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off windows automatically connecting to open hotspots follow these steps:

1-Click on start and click on settings ( or use the shortcut " Windows key + I " )

2-Click on network & Internet

3-Click on Wi-fi

4-Under Wi-Fi Sense, turn off the “Connect to suggested hotspots” option to disable the feature.

[Source](http://Under%20Wi-Fi%20Sense,%20turn%20off%20the%20%E2%80%9CConnect%20to%20suggested%20hotspots%E2%80%9D%20option%20to%20disable%20the%20feature.)

Comment: I have the option under Wi-Fi Services not Wi-Fi Sense. Still thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered or chose that this is the answer @gaazkam